# How do i make a button with delayed reactivation time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a button which i want it to activate something. But i don't want it to be constantly activated, as i want it to be with a 10 - 20 seconds delay before you can activate it again.

Comment: Can i ask you why?

Comment: Things you need: an AND system, a memory cell to stay in a specific state and a 20 second delay timer. Someone else can figure out how to combine these (plus eventually some other details you'll need) and make an answer out of it, I don't have time to do that now. Good luck!

Comment: The question [What is the terminal velocity of a sheep?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178726/what-is-the-terminal-velocity-of-a-sheep) is about a possible solution for this problem.

Comment: @Philipp As much as I love that question, it has nothing to do with this question at all and does not provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: Sure it does: Drop an animal on a pressure plate to create a delayed reaction.

Comment: @Philipp having used the sheep solution i can confirm there is no way to get 20 seconds of sheep freefall for the delay needed due to world height

Comment: @Flaunting What if you chain multiple sheep towers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it took a little bit of time but I solved that problem.

> - Red = Input
> - Blue = Output
> - Green = Redstonedust
> - Orange = Special Event :o

[image: Overview]
<sub>Rightclick on the picture and press show picture to enlarge the image.</sub>

The problem you have is to block the input from the button for a specific time. I used a piston for that. The pisten blocks the redstone signal.

The thing on the upper right keeps the signal active. That means that the pisten is moving the block over the redstone and the butten is doing nothing anymore.

[image: Special Levler]
<sub>Rightclick on the picture and press show picture to enlarge the image.</sub>

How you are able to build such a thing you find [here](http://minecraft.wonderhowto.com/how-to/make-buttons-work-like-levers-minecraft-using-t-flip-flop-0135196/)! Further more you need a thing that activate the button if the (for example 10 - 20 secounds) time is over.

For that you need the special creation from uncle Gerret that is to the upper left.

[image: Delay]
<sub>Rightclick on the picture and press show picture to enlarge the image.</sub>

You can make this as long as you want to and also delay each Repeater as you want to. You can make whatever delay you want. If you put a Repeater on four ticks it is a delay of 0,4 secounds. That means you need 50 Repeater in a row to delay the time for 20 secounds.

One more screenshot from the back and you should be able to build that little thing.

[image: Backview]
<sub>Rightclick on the picture and press show picture to enlarge the image.</sub>

Do not forget the Reapeater next to the piston otherwise something crazy will happen...

Keep in mind that I was ignoring the place. You coul'd put my solution in a smaller space than I have done...

---

Here is a example how you could place the Repeater for less space usage (20 secounds delay):

[image: Less Space]

It is just a little bit bigger than in the pictures above...

Comment: I hope he wasnt after a really compact design

Comment: Could this be done with a hopper timer instead of the repeater method, would really compact the design. and allow for precise time changes

Comment: @flaunting Well coul'd be i do not know what a hopper timer is and how it is working... But if it is doing the same like my delay machine it is working.

Comment: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYwzd62cLSw) you would use the piston in the design to block the signal, i can't post an answer as i am at work but this should work

Comment: @flaunting it will working likly but the problem is that you have to build a thing that is activating the hopper timer and a thing that is disabling the timer. What is not that easy as my solution.

Comment: Because if you press the button the timer has to start and if the timer is finished it has to stop.

Comment: It takes up a lot less space, which in my opinion is more important

Comment: @Flaunting well you can make it how you want I only know this and it is working. You can put your answer later here to show me how this is working. Would be a intresting solution with a hopper timer...